# PHP: curl post url return #21

Tags: php, curl

I want get result from url

> Code :

```
function getNum(){
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://name.com/get/");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://name.com/info/');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.4.2004.13 Safari/027.46'); 
    print_r($ch);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
echo getNum();
```

also, if i don't use **TIMEOUT** crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set CURLOPT_POST to 1, but you haven't set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with any data to send - could that be it?

Comment: Yes, this url no parameter

Comment: I add it and work : curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"");